# Oracle BI EE filter on same dimension

Tags: oracle, obiee

I am new to OBIEE and would like to create an analysis where I can place one next to the other 2 columns with figures from same dimension but with different data.
To better explain it: let's say that in Dim1 we have Invoices and Payments as members. We also have other dims as Date, Invoice Number and so on. This would be the current output:

```
Date         | Dim1     | Invoice Number  | Amount
10/01/17       Invoice    1234              -450
10/02/17       Payment    1234               450
```

So, what I want is, instead of creating 2 reports, one for the Invoices and the other one for Payments, a single report with the following output:

```
Invoice Date | Invoice  | Payment date  | Payment  | Invoice Number  | Amount inv | Amount paid
10/01/17       Invoice    10/02/17        Payment    1234              -450         450
```

Is this kind of output achievable inside OBIEE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not trying to "filter on same dimension" but you are trying to convert rows into columns.

While it is possible to cheat your way around this it is definitely not something which is suggested! You are facing an analytical system - not Excel.

If this is an actual requirement and not simply a "I wish to see it this way" then the best approach is to store the data properly.

Second-best approach is to model it in the RPD with different logical table sources.

Last and the option NOT to go for right away is what you are asking for: Doing it in the front-end.

Apart from that: It's "analyses" that you are working with in OBI. If you have a "report" then you are in BI Publisher which is a completely different tool.

Comment: Thanks, it's Analysis indeed, not report.. And it's not a "nice to see" feature, it's taking a lot of time to gather all required data and there for I would like this output presented

Comment: You are misunderstanding me. My point is that by attacking this from the front end you are attacking it from the wrong side. Wrong because it's tje side witj the most effort and especially non-reusable effort because you need to repeat this for every time you need it. That is precisely why OBI works with models and not with queries so things become reusable. Also with all the gui tricks you probably "develop yorself into a functional corner"

Comment: OK, now I understand it! I should build up a model or change the existing one, that will split the required item into 2 separated dimensions and then it's pretty easy to use it, right?

Comment: Yes. The idea is to have the transformation logic done before you get to the front end. This way every request hitting that topic uses the same logic. Otherwise you'll have to build it in Answers when you do analyses, in BIP when you do reports, in Excel when you use SmartView AND in any outside system when you use web services. If you encapsualte it in the RPD all those consumers will use the same. And if you can push it to the physical model via ETL that's even better. Because the transformation will run once only when the data is written and not N times for each single data access